System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.'
[HttpPost]
[Route("LoginTest")]
public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody] LoginDTO login)
{
    // Fetch user
    var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == login.Username && u.Password == login.Password);

    if (user == null)
    {
        return Unauthorized("Invalid username or password.");
    }

    if (user.UserType == "Client")
    {
        // code throws error on this line
        var client = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.UserId == user.UserId);

        if (client == null)
        {
            // Handle case where client is null
            return NotFound("Client data not found.");
        }

        UserCDTO cDTO = new UserCDTO
        {
            Username = user.Username,
            Address = user.Address,
            CustomerName = client.CustomerName,
            Age = client.Age,
            Gender = client.Gender,
            ContactInfo = client.ContactInfo,
        };

        return Ok(cDTO);
    }
}

// Entities and DTO
public class UserCDTO 
{ 
    //User Inputs 
    public string? Username { get; set; } 
    public string? Password { get; set; } 
    public string? Address { get; set; } 
    //Customer Inputs 
    public string? CustomerName { get; set; } 
    public string? Age { get; set; } 
    public string? Gender { get; set; } 
    public string? ContactInfo { get; set; } 
}
public partial class Customer 
{ 

    public int CustomerId { get; set; } 
    public int? UserId { get; set; } 
    public string? CustomerName { get; set; } 
    public string Age { get; set; } = null!; 
    public string Gender { get; set; } = null!; 
    public string? ContactInfo { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; } = 
            new List<Order>(); 
    public virtual User? User { get; set; } 
} 

This code handles user authentication for a web app. It checks if the provided username and password match a user in the database. If the user is a client,it retrieves their details and (this is where it stops).
Otherwise, it returns an unauthorized or not found message.

Well - what is the datatype of UserId in your Customers entity - and what is the datatype of UserId on your Users entity ?

They are both int In my database I already check that...

Post your Customer and UserCDTO models.

public class UserCDTO
{
//User Inputs
public string? Username { get; set; }
public string? Password { get; set; }
public string? Address { get; set; }
   //Customer Inputs
   public string? CustomerName { get; set; }
   public string? Age { get; set; }
   public string? Gender { get; set; }
   public string? ContactInfo { get; set; }

}

public partial class Customer
{
public int CustomerId { get; set; }
public int? UserId { get; set; }

public string? CustomerName { get; set; }

public string Age { get; set; } = null!;

public string Gender { get; set; } = null!;

public string? ContactInfo { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; } = new List<Order>();

public virtual User? User { get; set; }

}

Are you sure age is a string?

thats not the point but changed it

Moved your comments to your question code. Please check if it is correct and remove the comments.

Your posted Customer does have an int? UserId, but your posted UserCDTO does not have any UserId property. So that's not the correct User class that you got from db.Users - please update to the correct one (you can edit your post)

Check your Customer type. It appears you have an int32 column in your database that cannot be cast to one of your Customer type properties, which is a string.
